# How to get data with type smallint, using Select query from PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT e FROM  person e where type like 3
```

I have an exception after executing this query. `type` is `smallint`.

> No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Why would you use `like`? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm sorry for that, I did not use PostgreSQL before. Now I found that need to use = instead of like.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT e FROM person e where type = '3';
it is funny)

Comment: `'3'` is a character literal, not a number. If `type` is defined as a numeric value, you should use a number literal `3` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `like` operator can only be applied on two strings. Here, you are attempting to apply it to a `smallint` column and a numeric literal, which, as you've seen, will not work. Instead, you should use the simple `=` operator:

```
SELECT e FROM person e WHERE type = 3
```